# Kill processes run in directory (recursive)

Tags: linux, bash, debian, sh

Is it possible to kill all processes run in one directory? Processes have the same user.
For example (runing processes  ):

```
/bin/1/a/p1  
/bin/1/b/p2  
/bin/2/a/p3
```

And I want kill all processes from `/bin/1/` (`/bin/1/a/p1` and `/bin/1/b/p2`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say:

```
ps aw | awk '/\/bin\/1\// {print $1}' | xargs kill -9
```

EDIT: In order to ensure that this doesn't kill any unintended command as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826405/kill-processes-run-in-directory-recursive#comment27770623_18826623) you could say:

```
ps aw o pid,command | awk '$2 ~ /^\/bin\/1\// {print $1}' | xargs kill -9
```

Comment: You'd better do `'$5 ~ /\/bin\/1\//'` since you're command will also kill `ls /bin/1/`

Comment: Also, be aware that processes can change their own name.

Answer (score 1):

```
pkill [-s SIGSPEC] -f '/bin/1/'
```